# Is it possible to set a *constant* lowest CPU frequency under the modern PSTATE driver?

Tags: cpu-frequency

The new `pstate` Intel driver pisses me off for good, because they have removed the good old `powersave` governor that allowed me to set the lowest available CPU frequency and run my numerical simulations for hours or days in a nicely silent, cold laptop. To make things worse, what they call now `powersave` is essentially the old governor `ondemand`, i.e. a mode in which the CPU frequency rams up with the load, and with it the damn fan noise:

> Since these policies are implemented in the driver, they are not same as the
>   cpufreq scaling governors implementation, even if they have the same name in
>   the cpufreq sysfs (scaling_governors). For example the "performance" policy is
>   similar to cpufreq(TM) "performance" governor, but "powersave" is completely
>   different than the cpufreq "powersave" governor. The strategy here is similar
>   to cpufreq "ondemand", where the requested P-State is related to the system load.

(Extracted from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt)

Now, please, is there any other way to keep my CPU frequency at a minimum? It's really important for me. I just prefer to dump the laptop through the window if I eventually cannot set a constant, lowest CPU frequency. That is how I use my laptop and that is what I want a laptop for, and I have been trying to achieve this for several days already!

I'm trying this, and it doesn't work:

```
echo 42 | sudo dd of=/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_pref_pct
```

to set the maximum speed at 42%, and it doesn't have any affect, the CPU keeps on going to 100% whenever I do something. What am I doing wrong? (should I restart some service or something?)

Is there any way to get this? Also, will a non-Intel CPU allow me to do that? I don't mind buying another laptop it that is going to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you played with `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_*`?

Comment: @Patrick I don't know, I have tried many things. I will have a look at it. If you know how to do this, please post it as an answer.

Comment: `cpupower frequency-set -u 800MHz` should do (assuming `800MHz` is the minimum speed of your cpu - so as to set the max the same as the min); to reset it just use the same command and replace `800MHz` with whatever the maximum speed of your cpu is; for more information consult the manual for `cpupower` and `cpupower frequency-set`

Comment: @don_crissti Are you sure you don't have *intel_pstate=disable* in grub? That's the only way I can do that, but then it is using the old acpi_cpufreq driver, which is not my question.

Comment: @don_crissti What is the advantage of Archlinux over Debian? (in your opinion). I might give it a try.

Comment: :) I don't know... what is the advantage of BMW over Mercedes-Benz ?

Comment: @don_crissti It could be that you think it is more solid, that is based on rpm or deb packages, or who knows

Comment: @don_crissti Please do me a favour. What is the output of "uname -r" you get? - Maybe the problem is in the kernel I am using.

Comment: Works OK with 4.15.3 and the older 4.14.13. If I have the time I'll try also the lts kernel. My cpu is a Sandy Bridge fwiw.

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks for your patience. One more thing: please make sure that you are able to set a fixed *constant* lowest frequency, no matter the load. Because setting the "powersave" governor is not enough. The powersave governor with the pstate driver is similar to the old governor "ondemand". It's not a fixed frequency policy any more. Are you really able to set a fixed frequency, load the cpu with some intensive task and still see that the frequency doesn't ram up but remain at the minimum you have set?

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks. Now I need to know why it is not working for me.

Comment: @don_crissti It seems to work now. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 26):

Well, well, turns out that the new `pstate` Intel driver is awesome, but first one needs to practice a bit of the ancient, lost art of *reading the documentation.*

I'll leave my question as it is because, judging by all the grief and frustration I see scattered all around the internet, I am not the first to have this issues.

The new CPU driver has lots of options, but I will restrict my explanation to something simple and, for me, more than enough and satisfactory. First of all:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-cpupower
```

(or the equivalent in your non-debian based distros)

There are now 2 behaviors (governors) with the names `powersave` and `performance` but that is quite an unfortunate naming scheme, because these governors have nothing to do with those that bear the same names in the old driver:

- `powersave` means now *variable frequency that depends on the load*, i.e. this is essentially the old `ondemand` governor. You get to set the minimum and maximum frequency, and if that maximum frequency is set to the maximum frequency your CPU is able of (which I believe it's the default) then you don't save a crap. You may even crank up the minimum frequency to the second highest value, and the result will be the CPU nearly at full throttle 24/7 and the governor will still be named *powersave*. They should have named this governor VARIABLE or something similar, avoiding a lot of confusion among users and sparing the developers a lot of false reports of kernel bugs.
- `performance` means here *constant frequency, no matter the load*, and this depends on what the user has set as maximum. When this governor is set, the mininum frequency is ignored and the CPU runs at the frequency you set as maximum. If as such you have set a very low frequency, then you will not see any special performance or anything, you just will get a slowed down CPU at constant frequency. So they'd better named this governor CONSTANT or something similar, sparing frustration to many people like me, used to the old scheme.

So, here are some examples that work like a charm, at least with kernel 4.14. I will use as minimum and maximum frequency the values for my CPU: 0.4 and 3.1 GHz. See yours with `cpupower frequency-info`

**CONSTANT, LOWEST FREQUENCY IN ALL CORES**

This IS what I wanted! We get that by setting the constant frequency governor and setting the lowest available frequency as the maximum:

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance
sudo cpupower frequency-set -u 400MHz
```

**CONSTANT, HIGHEST FREQUENCY IN ALL CORES**

(You see this asked very often for desktop computers where it makes sense, although there are also people out there willing to destroy their laptop fan)

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance
sudo cpupower frequency-set -u 3100MHz
```

**VARIABLE FREQUENCY BETWEEN THE MINIMUM AND MAXIMUM POSSIBLE FREQUENCIES IN ALL CORES**

(this was called *ondemand* with the old `acpi-cpufreq` driver)

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave
sudo cpupower frequency-set -d 400MHz
sudo cpupower frequency-set -u 3100MHz
```

**VARIABLE FREQUENCY BETWEEN THE MINIMUM AND A MODERATE FREQUENCY IN ALL CORES**

(maybe because you want to get some more speed when required but you don't want to reach the maximum and hear the fan blowing like mad)

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave
sudo cpupower frequency-set -d 400MHz
sudo cpupower frequency-set -u 1200MHz
```

And so on. It is very easy and works really well. You can set too a constant low frequency in one core where the heavy numerical stuff is running, while you leave a variable frequency in other core where you launch the more usual stuff (email, web browsing...). See `taskset` for more info.

Comment: How are you verifying that `performance` governor actually sets a constant cpu frequency? When I do `watch -x grep -E '^model name|^cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo ` the numbers bounce around all over, even when I change the governor to `performance`

Comment: Sadly doesn't work for me either. `cpupower frequency-info` has bizarre output like `frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 1.20 GHz....current CPU frequency: 3.16 GHz` maybe it's the funky laptop I'm using [dell inspiron].  The only change I notice is if I change `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq`  then my idle freq. goes down slightly.  Under load all cores still go all the way to the CPU max :(

Comment: Did you also tried using `cpufrequtils`? or [`tlp`](https://linrunner.de/tlp/)?

Comment: It seems like this answer is no longer true. Intel pstate doesn't seem to let you tune the frequency manually if you have hwp enabled.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me with:

```
echo "50" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct
```

it run only 50% performance/speed while CPU load is 100%

Comment: How can I make these changes persistent between reboots?

Answer (score 2):

After wasting many days in searching for a solution to set a constant frequency (to run a scientific experiment), I finally gave up. I've tried many different solutions including the `performance` governor ([as suggested by Mephisto](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424801/104917)), changing between `active` and `passive` mode of the intel_pstate driver, disabling the PPC protection, switching from intel_pstate to acpi-cpufreq, etc.

None of these options have any effect in setting a constant frequency. Then, I've found this comment in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt):

> For contemporary Intel processors, the frequency is controlled by the
> processor itself and the P-states exposed to software are related to
> performance levels. The idea that frequency can be set to a single
> frequency is fiction for Intel Core processors. Even if the scaling
> driver selects a single P state the actual frequency the processor
> will run at is selected by the processor itself.

So, **there's no a reliable way to do that**, P-States are just suggestions, the hardware would continue to decide on its own. On my processor (Intel J4105), it seems that the hardware completely ignores the settings coming from the software.